# How to search and replace string in a file in Perl

Tags: perl

The content of my input file is shown below:

```
abc\**def\ghi**\abc\!!!!!
abc\**4nfiug\frgrefd\gtefe\wf4fs**\abc\df3gwddw
abc\**eg4/refw**\abc\f3
```

I need to replace whatever string in between `abc \ --------------\abc` in my input file with `ABC\CBA`.

I have tried something like below to get the strings that need to be replaced. But I get stuck when I need to use the search and replace:

```
my $string1 = qr/abc\W+([^a]+)/;
my $string2 = map{/$string1/ => " "} @input_file; # The string that needs to be replaced
my $string3 = 'ABC\CBA'  # String in that. I want it to replace to

s/$string2/$string3/g
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh,"<", "tryit.txt" or die $!;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    $line =~ s/(abc\\)(.*?)(\\abc)/$1ABC\\CBA$3/;
    print $line;
}
```

gives the following with the input data.

```
abc\ABC\CBA\abc\!!!!!
abc\ABC\CBA\abc\df3gwddw
abc\ABC\CBA\abc\f3
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.This is almost what I want.The results printed on the unix is what I want.However, I need to overwrite my input file with the result obtained.FYI, my input file is still the same before and after executing the script.

Comment: There's dozens of ways to do this depending on how often this needs to be used.  The easiest was (in my opinion), is to write the output to a temp file, delete the original, and then rename the temp to the original input file name.

Comment: Based on @TLP's edits, I'm guessing my methods are old school :-P

Comment: @steven You can use the -i switch from the command line to do in-place edit.

Answer (score 11):

```
perl -i -pe 's/this/that/g;'  file1
```

Comment: To avoid all the escape characters and improve code readability (avoiding the "Leaning Toothpick Syndrom": en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome), you can also replace the "/" delimiters/separators by a hashtag "#" ===>  perl -i -pe 's#this#that#g;'  file1

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., is the magic in `-i` and/or `-p`? And why?

Comment: @PeterMortensen   read  https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html/

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner to fix a file:

```
perl -plwe 's/abc\\\K.*(?=\\abc)/ABC\\CBA/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Or as a script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/abc\\\K.*(?=\\abc)/ABC\\CBA/;
    print;
}

__DATA__
abc\**def\ghi**\abc\!!!!!
abc\**4nfiug\frgrefd\gtefe\wf4fs**\abc\df3gwddw
abc\**eg4/refw**\abc\f3
```

The `\K` (keep) escape sequence means these characters will not be removed. Similarly, the look-ahead assertion `(?= ... )` will keep that part of the match. I assumed you only wanted to change the characters in between.

Instead of `\K` one can use a look-behind assertion: `(?<=abc\\)`. As a personal preference, I used `\K` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the substitution to operate on the default variable `$_`, you have to use the `=~` operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @input_file = split /\n/, <<'__EOF__';
abc\**def\ghi**\abc\!!!!!
abc\**4nfiug\frgrefd\gtefe\wf4fs**\abc\df3gwddw
abc\**eg4/refw**\abc\f3
__EOF__

my $pattern = qr/abc\\.*\\abc/;       # pattern to be matched
my $string2 = join "\n", @input_file; # the string that need to be replaced
my $string3 = 'ABC\CBA';              # string i that i want it to replace to

$string2 =~ s/$pattern/$string3/g;
print $string2;
```

Comment: Thanks choroba. I have tried to open my file and do all the searching and replacing.however, it seems lk no effect on my input file. i have tried below: foreach my $file ($input) { open(I,$file) or die $!; <I>; while(<I>) {  my $pattern = qr/abc\\.*\\abc/;my $string2 = join "\n", @input_file;my $string3 = 'ABC\CBA';$string2 =~ s/$pattern/$string3/g; print $string2; } close(I) }

Comment: Why do you first split on newline, then join that split with newline? Seems redundant.

Comment: @TLP: If you asked me, I just wanted to use `@input_file` as the author of the question.

Answer (score 1):

To address your comment about replacing text "inplace" in the file directly, you can use the [`-i`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) switch for a one-liner. In a script, you can perhaps look at using [`Tie::File`](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aFile), which allows read-write access to lines of a file as (mutable) elements in an array. To copy Mike/TLP's answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, "Tie::File", "tryit.txt" or die $!;

# I think you have to use $_ here (done implicitly)
while (@file) {
    s/(abc\\)(.*?)(\\abc)/$1ABC\\CBA$3/;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Use `for` instead of `while`, and the `print` isn't necessary as `Tie::File` will update the file. (a colleague of mine have got a CopyPasteInheritance bug from this code snippet ^^)